# Sql: How to properly check if a record exists that matches 3 column

Tags: sql

I have read through the forum but i could not find any example or answer for check existing record for multiple column.

Question:
To check if an entry exist if match 3 column. There is 9 column in the table if 2 column entry match are not counted as existing record.

Comment: please give some examples ...

Comment: Any example of a table you're trying to querry? Any unsuccessfull attempts you've tried?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'XXX' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS existing_row_count FROM tablename WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

If existing_row_count returns greater than zero then we can say that there is at least one match.  You can try this also:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

Thus, you can get the matching row id numbers. And if we combine those two queries:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS existing_row_count FROM tablename WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ? AND col3 = ?
```

Comment: how about those 3 column are primary key, i having error when even 1 of it match , it throw me an error of duplicated entry

Comment: As far as I understand from your question I can only suggest this. If you shared some part or structure of your table I would have said more. You push me into a dark room and want me to design a perfect car.